# Can we implement the Two Get Request on the same resource

Tags: java, spring, rest

Can any here suggest how can i implement the two GET request with different parameter on the same resource's function.

ex:

```
GetMapping("/Transaction")
GetMapping("/Transactions")
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? Please give a more specific example.

Comment: Why? /Transactions should return a list of transactions and /Transactions/1234/ should return the transaction with that id. /Transaction is not needed in proper REST.

Comment: I want to invoke the function where the mapping should be of the different Get Requests.

Comment: @dbl i am sorry i cant paste the code here since its the project policy...Please let me know if you want to know more in details

Comment: @luk2302 that was just the example.Lets just take for instance GetMapping("/Transactions") GetMapping("/allTransactions")

Comment: Still stands: why? "allTransactions" is a bad REST resource once again,

Comment: @luk2302 why is `"allTransactions"` a bad REST resource? A naming policy might differ from the traditional/standard but still be correct. BTW, the question isn't about constructing a proper REST API.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko thanks a lot man ..that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@GetMapping(path = {"/Transaction", "/Transactions"})
```

[`path`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#path--) is a `String[]`, so you can specify more than one path.

Comment: You can see from the docs at https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html#path-- that `GetMapping` takes a `String[]` instead of a `String` which hints that passing multiple paths in this way will work.